# How to bind a vertical constraint programatically to a view?

Tags: ios, ios7, nslayoutconstraint

I am reading into implementing iAd into my application.
Apple has provided a basic banner [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite_Storyboard/Listings/BasicBanner_BasicBanner_TextViewController_m.html).

I have a problem porting the solution to my UITableViewController. Since I don't use any xib file in order to bind the introduced `NSLayoutConstraint` to my tableview:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint;
```

If this isn't bound properly, I wont be able to shrink the view according to the ad's size:

```
- (void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;

    // all we need to do is ask the banner for a size that fits into the layout area we are using
    CGSize sizeForBanner = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];

    // compute the ad banner frame
    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {

        // bring the ad into view
        contentFrame.size.height -= sizeForBanner.height;   // shrink down content frame to fit the banner below it
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.size.height = sizeForBanner.height;
        bannerFrame.size.width = sizeForBanner.width;

        // if the ad is available and loaded, shrink down the content frame to fit the banner below it,
        // we do this by modifying the vertical bottom constraint constant to equal the banner's height
        //
        NSLayoutConstraint *verticalBottomConstraint = self.bottomConstraint;
        verticalBottomConstraint.constant = sizeForBanner.height;
        [self.view layoutSubviews];

    } else {
        // hide the banner off screen further off the bottom
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        _contentView.frame = contentFrame;
        [_contentView layoutIfNeeded];
        _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];
}
```

The question is how do I bind programatically the bottomConstraint to the vertical bottom of my view in order to shrink it afterwards?